# Is this a sentry palm?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I "inherited" a plant and was trying to identify it (to understand how to take care of it - plants usually have a hard time with me).

I belive this is a [sentry palm](https://www.ourhouseplants.com/plants/howea-palms) (from photo matches gathered on Internet) but my leaves seem much more narrow than the ones on the pictures.

The plant is in France and is probably not a fancy one (in the sense that it should probably be available in Ikea or a general plant store).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note: this question should be made to gardening.stackexchange.com

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: I had no idea that such a site existed (I will have to look again at the new members of the network). Yes, that would have definitely been a better place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly doubt that this is a sentry palm. It seems to be a [golden cane palm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dypsis_lutescens), also known as areca palm or butterfly palm, *Dyopsis lutescens*.

Here is an image for comparison:

[image]

And here is a close up of the leaf:

[image]

This whole structure is just 1 leaf. What you called *"leaves"* in your question are actually just leaflets (or *foliolum* in Latin).